# Ignore empty notes/delete empty notes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can't seem to find any existing answer for the following:

I have the below script written to set notes across a range on sheet from a separate source sheet, however, when running this function, blank notes are also created If the source cell is blank.

Is there any way to prevent notes being set unless the source cell contains text?

```
function addNotes() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = sh.getSheetByName("Notes")
  const destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Copy");
  let destRange = destSheet.getRange("C5:I58");
  let notesRange = source.getRange("Q2:W55").getValues();
  
  destRange.setNotes(notesRange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Simply change every occurance of blank in notesRange to null.

You can not simply change col to null, you need to change the array value cols[index].

**Before running script**

[image]

**After running script**

[image]

**Script**

```
function addNotes() {
  try {
    let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let source = sh.getSheetByName("Notes")
    let destSheet = sh.getSheetByName("Notes");  // Change to Copy
    let destRange = source.getRange("D1:E5");
    let notesRange = source.getRange("A1:B5").getValues();
    notesRange.forEach( row => row.forEach( (col,index,cols) => { if( col === "" ) cols[index] = null; } ) );
    console.log(notesRange);
  
    destRange.setNotes(notesRange);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Range.setNotes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNotes(Object))

Comment: Thanks for the help WizEd. I have just realised, however, that empty notes are being created because I have formulas in the source range for my notes that retrieve the data, therefore it seems that the script is considering these cells as 'Not blank' and setting an empty note in the destination range. I think this also affects your function as it produces the same result as my script due to there being formulas in the range. Just need to figure out a workaround...

Comment: Of course, if there is a formula in a cell from `let notesRange = source.getRange("A1:B5").getValues();` there will be a value.  Even if the formula produces a blank there will be no note produced.  So I believe my script is working correctly.